# How to stop and start EJB scheduler from JBoss console?

Tags: jboss, ejb

Below method is executing every 10 seconds I want to stop this scheduler from  JBoss

```
 console@TransactionTimeout(value = 14400)@Schedule(dayOfWeek = "*", hour ="*",minute="*",second="10",persistent =false)public void AddFinDocs(){log.info("AddFinDocs:Scheduler Started...");}
```